# How to show message of some special characters in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, messaging

I want to display the message of success and error green/red which I am already displaying but here is I am having problem

When I entering a message of some special characters of some other like

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('')
                    ->with("modal_message_danger", "Heslo, které jste zadali, je neplatné.");
```

It shows me only the red bar of error, not the message which is written inside that is "Heslo, které jste zadali, je neplatné."

But when i enter in english language like:

```
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('')
              ->with("modal_message_danger", "password change is incorrect")
```

Its successfully shows me error message.

What is happening here I need your help. Your help will be appreciated!

```
@if ($message = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session::get('modal_message_danger'))
                  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-block">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">Ã—</button>
                        <span>{{ $message }}</span>
                   </div>
@endif
```

Comment: try `{!! html_entity_decode($string, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!} ` where you are displaying the code

Comment: @MayuriPansuriya didn't you mean *encode* instead of *decode*?

Comment: where to write this and how?

Comment: where did you use `modal_message_danger` in your blade file?

Comment: Undefined variable: string

Comment: replace it with `$modal_message_danger`

Comment: please see my edit code where i am using model_message_danger

Comment: can u please edit into my code >

Comment: i will be thankful if u show me in my code please

Comment: `<span>{!!html_entity_decode ($message,ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8') !!}</span>`

Comment: its still showing red bar not a message